# How to integrate paypal into my php project?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm developing an ecommerce website (as a project) and I want to integrate payment gateway in same.  In this project when a user clicks on a product at index page, he's redirected to product_detail.php where there is a **buy now** button which directs him to payment gateway, but I always get the error *"BAD_INPUT_ERROR: Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."*
  Here's a part of my code

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypalURL; ?>" method="post">
    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypalID; ?>">

    <!-- Specify a Buy Now button. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="INR">
    <INPUT TYPE="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">

    <!-- Specify URLs -->
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/search/cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://localhost/search/success.php'>

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">

</form>
```

Am I missing something? (I'm a beginner in php and I learned this from a website), also I wasn't able to turn on Auto return in my paypal sandbox account because they weren't able to validate my return URL. Do I need to host my project first so that it accepts my return URL?

Comment: Hi Deepti. Can you update the question to include the HTML output of the form as well please?

Comment: The fact that your return URL is **localhost** doesn't help in that the PP sandbox may have a hard time verifying. Technically you should be able to do this in a sandbox environment. Check for a setting in your PayPal sandbox account.

Comment: In the meantime, you can turn off auto-return:  [link]http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/paypal-sandbox-mode/